# How to repeat a loop in a CSV file in Jmeter?

Tags: loops, csv, jmeter

I understand there is while controller to loop to all the data in a csv file but if I want to loop the whole data set again, how would I do it?

e.g.

In CSV file

1. abc
2. qwe
3. zxc

Once I run execute it and I expect to loop 3 times

e.g.

- abc
- qwe
- zxc
- abc
- qwe
- zxc
- abc
- qwe
- zxc

so once the first loop is done, I'd expect it to start again and loop until the 3rd loop set is done.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and configure it to loop 9 times

Demo:

[image]

Depending on what you're trying to achieve you can play with ["Sharing Mode" setting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy/), by default each virtual user will read next line on each iteration however you might want to change this approach so each user would have individual access to the CSV file

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've tried what you setup on Jmeter but I still have the remaining iterations blank.
https://imgur.com/a/Lo8RAcD